# Execution Context on IObservable with nested Events

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Execution Context nested Events

Hi,
I would like to know a little bit more about the execution context of an `IObserver<T>` and related to “nested events”.

Basically when I compare it to linq-to-IEnumerable, I build up an expression tree and I gets executed when I call something like `ToList()`… etc.
For example

```
Var singleCustomer = from customer in customers
            Where customer.ID == 2
            Select customer.FirstOrDefault();
```

This is only an expression which gets executed (I assume when I execute `FirstOrDefault`)…
How does this work with the `IObservable` world? I assume it would work almost the same… I would be great to have some input on this…

This relates to my real question because I have some Event which is some sort of an event container.

```
event EventHandler<ContainerEventArgs> ContainerReady;
```

and the `ContainerEventArgs` would contain an Array of Coordinates… And I have to do an operation there to get out the particular coordinates (centercoordinate) I am looking for. 
The centercoordinates would the thing I really like to observe on. WhenEver this changes I would like to get Notified,..

In the standard .Net way without Rx I would do something like this to get my Coordinate Change Event for the CenterCoordinate.

```
ContainerReady += (s,e) => {
var container = e.GetContainer();
var coordinate = new point[e.CoordinatesArrayLength]();
e.CopyCoordinatesToArray(container);
if(coordinates != null){
  var particularCoordinate = from coordinate in coordinates.where(… center coordinates…).FirstOrDefault();
if(particularCoordinate != null){
  if(CenterCoordinateUpdated != null)
     {
        CenterCoordinateUpdated(this, new CenterCoordinateUpdatedEventArgs(){
           CenterPosition = particularCoordinates;
          }
     }
}

}
```

Assuming I have some second event like this:

```
event EventHandler<CenterCoordinatesUpdatedEventArgs> CenterCoordinateUpdated;
```

Ok long story … now How should I handle this with RX? What I have so far is this:

```
public IObservable<Container> GetContainers(){
     var containerSource = Observerable.FromeEventPattern< ContainerEventArgs>(this,”ContainerReady”);
var container = from evt in containerSource.Where(x=>x.EventArgs.GetContainer != null)
select evt.GetContainers();
return container;
}
```

So this returns an `IObservable<Container>()` but like I said I am more interested in the inner values …

I came up with this…

```
public IObservable<CenterCoordinates> GetContainers(){
     var containerSource = Observerable.FromeEventPattern< ContainerEventArgs>(this,”ContainerReady”);
var container = from evt in containerSource.Where(x=>x.EventArgs.GetContainer != null)
select evt.GetContainers();
var centerCoordinate = from cc in container
             select GetCenterCoordinates(cc); //Get CenterCoordinates does the Array copy stuff
return centerCoordinate.SkipWhile(x=>x … center condition… );
}
```

Does my `SkipWhile` and `GetCenterCoordinates` methods make sense? Or do I subscribe anyway to any event (related to my intro with IEnumerable) because I need to unpack the coordinates first?…When is the Observable Expression-Tree executed? Or do I not need to pay attention on that(performance)?
Is there a better way to handle this using Subjects or publish other events? Is this RX-Style? Any improvement suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement are really suited for Rx, you just need a little more practice :-)

Let me try and help. I hope I got your requirements right.

Your query could be written in this simple way:

```
public IObservable<CenterCoordinates> GetContainers()
{
    var containerSource = Observerable.FromeEventPattern<ContainerEventArgs>(this, "ContainerReady");

    var query = containerSource
        .Select(ev => ev.EventArgs.GetContainer) // project event args into containers
        .Where(container => container != null) // filter null containers
        .SelectMany(container => GetCenterCoordinates(container))  // expand the stream of containers into a stream of center coordinates
        .Where(cc => .. center condition ..);  // filter only center that match a certain condition

    return query;
}
```

if you prefer the query syntax, you can also write it like this:

```
public IObservable<CenterCoordinates> GetContainers()
{
    var containerSource = Observerable.FromeEventPattern<ContainerEventArgs>(this, "ContainerReady");

    var query = from ev in containerSource
                let container = ev.EventArgs.GetContainer
                where container != null
                from cc in GetCenterCoordinates(container)
                where cc .. center condition ..
                select cc;

    return query;
}
```

Get familiar with `SelectMany`: it is one of the most important operators in LINQ (both LINQ to objects, and Rx).

And a small correction: the LINQ queries that we're talking about here are not translated by the compiler into expression trees. They are translated into a chain of extension methods, like I've shown in my first example. Expression trees are used in more complex scenarios (e.g. LINQ to SQL).